# Testing fasthttp with httptest

Tags: testing, go, fasthttp

I am wondering how I can test an application that's written with [fasthttp](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp) using the [httptest package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/) in the base library of Go.

I found [this guide](https://elithrar.github.io/article/testing-http-handlers-go/) which explains the testing pretty well, but the issue is that httptest does not satisfy the `http.Handler` interface so I have no idea how to do the `http.HandlerFunc` since fasthttp uses it's own `fasthttp.ListenAndServe` that's incompatible.

Any ideas on how to create a wrapper, or how to otherwise test a fasthttp written library end to end?

Comment: This is the downside to third-party muxes that don't follow the stdlib Handler interface. If the library doesn't include its own equivalent to `httptest`, you're SOL, and most of them don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible approaches. Unit testing a handler isn't really viable as you would need to create a [RequestCtx](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestCtx) and stub/mock all necessary fields.

Instead, I would unit test the code that your fasthttp handlers call out 
to. I would do e2e testing of the actual handlers themselves.

There is an [in memory listener](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp/fasthttputil#InmemoryListener) implementation that you could use to avoid actually listening on a TCP port or Unix socket. You would initialise the server but serve on this listener instead of on a network connection.

You would then create a HTTP client and call the relevant methods as normal but use this listener as the transport.

If you stub/fake anything that your handlers interact with then you could make this in-memory only with no external dependencies, i.e. like a unit test but it will actually doing a full system test.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. After looking at GitHub I decided to rewrite the application to go back to standard net/http as there is just more support behind it and the tool integration is also much better. But I am also doing the stubbing/faking on the handlers to simplify testing. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a complete example of using an in-memory listener, please. Thanks a lot. I am having a bit of trouble understanding it. Also, do you think you could make it work with `WebSocket`s? It'd save me a lot of trouble if you know the answer to the latter question already.

Comment: @MohamedBana you can find good examples of in-memory listener here https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/blob/master/server_test.go#L3831 TestMultipleServe or https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/blob/master/server_test.go#L1054 TestServerTLS. For websocket tests with Fasthttp and Gorilla see https://github.com/fasthttp/websocket/blob/master/client_server_test.go#L928 TestNetDialConnect

Answer (score 1):

```golang
func TestFasthttpServer(t *testing.T) {
    fSv := fasthttp.Server{}
    fSv.Handler = func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
        if string(ctx.Path()) == "/test" && string(ctx.Method()) == "GET" {
            ctx.WriteString("OK")
        }
    }

    ln := fasthttputil.NewInmemoryListener()

    go fSv.Serve(ln)

    client := http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialContext: func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return ln.Dial()
        },
    }}

    resp, _ := client.Get("http://localhost/test")
    respBody, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    assert.Equal(t, string(respBody), "OK")
}
```

[Credits](https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/golang-blazing-fast-unit-tests-fiber-fasthttp-http-internals-and-optimizing-http-server-tests-bbd1fe7b944b)

Valuable examples also could be found [here](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/issues/36).